# Swagger Tools Production Build Node js

Tags: deployment, webpack-production, swagger-tools

We implemented the swagger in our nodeJs application. As of now we are created production build using webpack and remove the controller and services file.

**bin/www.js**

```js
const YAML = require('yamljs');
const swaggerTools = require('swagger-tools');
const swaggerDoc = YAML.safeLoad('./swagger.yaml');

// swaggerRouter configuration
const swaggerOptions = {
  controllers: path.join(__dirname, '../public/javascripts/controllers'),
  useStubs: true, // Conditionally turn on stubs (mock mode)
};


// Initialize the Swagger middleware
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDoc, (middleware) => {
  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());

  // validate the security using JWT token
  app.use(middleware.swaggerSecurity({
      Bearer: auth.verifyToken
  }));
  // Validate Swagger requests
  app.use(middleware.swaggerValidator({
    validateResponse: true
  }));

  // Route validated requests to appropriate controller
  app.use(middleware.swaggerRouter(swaggerOptions));

  // Serve the Swagger documents and Swagger UI
  app.use(middleware.swaggerUi());

});
```

If we did the same in production build and the swagger middleware expecting the same path to resolve. after build we delete the public folder.

**Webpack code**

```js
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './bin/www',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'server.build.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  node: {
    // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
    __dirname: false, // if you don't put this is, __dirname
    __filename: false, // and __filename return blank or /
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Pleas help us to create a build using swagger middleware

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger tools is not a package bundler like webpack. So you will still need to provide it the controller files. Since you are deleting /public from prod then there is no way for swagger tools middleware to get the files it needs. Webpack in this case is basically building a dist from your code which is why it's ok to delete the controller and services.